# Calltree for c + + program to the standard library

Tags: c++, msmq

is there a way to make call trees or method invocation list for c++ programs which uses windows standard libraries.

Example:

i write c++ program where i use some libraries from windows, for example MSMQ function called "MQCreateQueue(...)" and now i want to see if i use this "MQCreateQueue(...)" function, which other functions are called by this function.

Link to [MQCreateQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701768%28VS.85%29.aspx) function

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put a breakpoint there in the debugger, and step through the function calls from there?

Comment: hi i can put brakpoint in code, but cant step in windows api code

Answer (score 0):

[VTune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTune) can build a callgraph, afaik.